# How to display the other decimal points in echarts (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to display the other decimal points in echarts for the example.
`.30.29` and `.02.03`.

here's the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-echarts-vzpvcm?file=src/app/app.component.html

```
   const data1 = [];

    data1.push(".3.02", "22", "3.2", ".3.0002", ".4.002", ".02.03");

    this.options = {
      tooltip: {
        formatter: this.getTooltipFormatter(),
        confine: true
      },
      xAxis: {
        data: xAxisData
      },
      yAxis: {},
      series: [
        {
          name: "sample1",
          type: "line",
          barCategoryGap: "0%",
          data: data1
        }
      ]
    };
```

Here is the current output.

[image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9q7J.png)

it doesn't display the `.3.02` and the other have decimal points

Comment: How `.3.02` is decimal point? either it should be `3.02` or `.302`

Comment: I have a data which is ```30.28``` and ```.3.02``` it didn't display the ```.3.02``` in echart

Comment: is there any possible to display the ```.3.02``` or ```.2.004``` in echarts?